# Orientation of images using nibabel

Tags: nifti, nibabel

I have started reading about the orientation of Nifti images and wanted to clarify some concepts. Here are some of the questions:

1. When accessing the data of an image: `image.get_fdata()` are the axes of the NumPy array always the same with respect to the anatomical axes? i.e. first axis -> left to right, second axis -> posterior to anterior, third axis -> inferior to superior?
2. What relation is there between the `qform` and the `sform` to the RAS+ scanner orientation?
3. As per the docs there are 4 types of `qform code` and `sform code` that modify the coordinates, what changes between them?

Any further comments on how all the concepts are related are appreciated.

Comment: I think that the orientation is obtained via the Affine Transform matrix, this [link](https://nipy.org/nibabel/coordinate_systems.html) might be useful.